# PostGIS function for pgRouting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, mapserver

I'm trying to create a function that will be essentially taking various parameters perform pgrouting with Dijkstra's algorithm, according to the user input as parameters. So the I'm making a minimal example which is the following:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _a_route(source integer, target integer)
 RETURNS SETOF record AS
 $$
 BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, time AS cost FROM roads_noded', $1, $2, false);
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This should be taking source and target as input and run the algorithm.

But I'm always getting the same error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM       instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function _a_route(integer,integer) line 3 at SQL statement
```

So what am I doing wrong here? SETOF record is supposed to be the equivalent of returning a table

Postgresql Version:   9.6.1
PostGIS  : 2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use SQL and also it's better not to return record, since you'd then always have to specify the columns when you use the function.

Do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _a_route(source integer, target integer)
RETURNS TABLE(seq integer, path_seq integer, node bigint, edge bigint, cost double precision, agg_cost double precision) AS
 $$
  SELECT d.seq, d.path_seq, d.node, d.edge, d.cost, d.agg_cost 
    FROM pgr_dijkstra(
  'SELECT id, source, target, time AS cost FROM roads_noded', $1, $2,    
   false) AS d;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you do use plpgsql, you have to do RETURN QUERY right before your SELECT statement, but in this case you don't need to use plpgsql.

This and many other pgrouting topics are covered in our upcoming book which is now in preview release and next preview release will be coming out early next week which includes the remaining chapters in draft form. http://locatepress.com/pgrouting

Comment: Thanks a lot....!!! You are right. There's no need for it to be plpgsql. So now that I have the function created, I assume that I need to be able to pass the parameters in mapserver's mapfile ? How's that possible ? I've been waiting for this book for some time now. When will it be fully released?

Comment: Probably another month or 2.  We just finished up the content now it's polishing time. But it has started selling and anyone that buys gets polished updates.  Regarding mapserver - you'd use runtime substitution - http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html  and then your DATA part you'd have something like DATA "geom FROM (SELECT r.*, e.geom FROM _a_route(%source%, %target%) AS r INNER JOIN your_edges AS e ON r.eget = e.id"  and pass the variables via http get

Comment: Thank you very much...!!  One more thing: the function I'm creating is not quite returning a table. It more like a comma separated value list under one column name "_a_router" and then "record". Is this a proper result?  I assume that the result will be the same if the function returns either a "SETOF record" or "table", right ? And apart from Runtime Subsitution, do you think php Mapscript would be another solution for passing values to the mapfile this way?

Comment: If you call it with SELECT f.* FROM _a_route(1,7) As f.  It should return all the rows and columns.  Don't call it like SELECT _a_route(1,7); which is what I suspect you are doing

Comment: Hello again...!! I've been trying this in a minimal example, meaning without using the runtime substitution yet but no chance so far. The statement is: DATA: "geom FROM (SELECT r.*, e.geom FROM _a_route(1,4)) AS r INNER JOIN roads_noded AS e ON r.edge = e.id using unique id using srid=2100".  The MS_ERRORFILE gives me the following error: Error (ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 1: ...T_Force2D("geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"id" from (SELECT r....      I hope this is not a type. The statement looks OK so far...

Comment: Sorry I forgot the alias part -  DATA: geom FROM (SELECT ....) AS foo USING UNIQUE id USING SRID=2100

Comment: I don't get it. I use the alias (AS r in this instance) but still. DATA "geom FROM (SELECT r.*, e.geom FROM _a_router(1,4)) AS r INNER JOIN roads_noded AS e ON r.edge = e.id using unique e.id using srid=2100". The MS_ERRORFILE indicates:    Error (ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "r"
LINE 1: ..."geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"e.id" from (SELECT r.*, e.geo...    I'm sure there's no "FROM" missing here...

Comment: Your whole query has to be in the FROM, so it should be :  DATA "geom FROM (SELECT r.*, e.geom FROM _a_router(1,4)) AS r INNER JOIN roads_noded AS e ON r.edge = e.id) AS foo USING UNIQUE id using srid=2100"

Comment: Oh...yeah. You're correct. I didn't see that typo, sorry. Now I'm getting this one: Error (ERROR:  column reference "geom" is ambiguous

Comment: Do you have a geom column returned as part of your _a_router.  If you are already doing the join in _a_router, you can drop the join with roads_noded entirely and the e.geom output.

Comment: oooooh... you're right. Indeed I am returning the geometry in the function. Now it's working. Thank you very much. I'm really new to this. :-)

Comment: I'm wondering if this whole process is wrong. I mean, would it be more useful if the stored query would take x1,y1 and x2,y2 as input rather than source, target?  The whole mechanism is built on Openlayers that send the click coordinates to a php script that calculates the closest node of the click. The clicks are x and y but the function takes source and target

Comment: Yes it would be much more straight forward to have the stored function take the coordinates and you do the closest check in the function.

Comment: hmm... so in my way I need to execute the "closest node" query inside the php script but the other way the php script only queries the stored function. Does it "cost" more my way? Is it a matter of right or wrong ?  But on the other hand MapServer subsitution variables need to change as well right?

Comment: Few things are a matter of right or wrong. The cost your way is probably a little more but probably trivially more.  So whatever is easiest for you to debug is probably most important.

Comment: Finally, I made it work.  Strangely enough I don't even need PHP at all. I created the PostGIS function that takes incoming x1,y1,(start point) x2, y2 (endpoint) which then calculates the closest point next to the clicks AND returns the geometry of DIjkstra's algorithm. I capture the clicks with OpenLayers and then pass them to MapServer as a Runtime Substitution variable. Then OpenLayers simply draw the Route as a new layer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that in plpgsql.

Return table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _a_route(source integer, target integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(id integer, source integer, target integer, cost double precision) AS
 $$
 BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, time AS cost FROM roads_noded', $1, $2, false);
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Return SETOF Record with OUT params:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _a_route(source integer, target integer, id OUT integer, source OUT integer, target OUT integer, cost OUT double precision)
 RETURNS SETOF TABLE(id integer, source integer, target integer, cost double precision) AS
 $$
 BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, time AS cost FROM roads_noded', $1, $2, false);
 END;
 $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```